# GIT to SVN migration perseverving user checkin data for multi-user

Tags: git, svn, git-svn, tortoisegit, smartgit

Question: I was wondering how you would preserve the user check info when migrating a GIT repo to a SVN.

Example:

Say that I have two repository.  One as a SVN and the other as a GIT rep.  Say that you have multiple checkin for different users ( user A, user B, user C) on the GIT repo.  When you merge over from the GIT to SVN repo, all the files get re-tagged with the user that does the merge.  Let's say its user C that does that merge.  ALl the files will be associated with user C instead of the original author.

There are tools that does the merge like SmartGit or even TortoiseGit, however they don't account for multi-users.

Is there any solution out there?

Any advice appropriated, Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

[SubGit](http://subgit.com/) is capable of doing this.

Comment: So say if you have a svn repo, as subgit generated repo, then a git clone of the subgit generated repo.  If i made changes on the clone, then then pushes the changes, it triggers an automatic sync with the svn.  What happens in the case when the computer has no connection to the svn, till later.  How does those changes get pushed?  From what I understand, all this stuff is generated from hooks.  If the svn offline, then how would you trigger that action?

Comment: I've tested with a local svn created repo and the name mapping works...but then when i got to a remote svn where there are specific user accounts, and i'm modifying the subgit author/passwd files it doesn't work.  I feel like i'm configuring something in correctly, but can't figure out what

Comment: Unfortunatley I'm not really experienced with SubGit, I just know that it supports that Git-SVN author mapping. It might be best to contact the mailing list: http://lists.tmatesoft.com/mailman/listinfo/subgit-users